# Translation of iPhone App

Tags: translation

I would like to localize my app (as suggested from Apple) to several languages like English, Spanish, French, etc...

Well I don't speak or understand all those languages, at least my translations look awkward to native speakers.

(Results from online translators are a first start but of course insufficient.)
So does anybody know a service/platform where I can get translations from human native speakers mutually.

For example:

I speak German mother tongue and need my app/text/website translated to English.

Some other guy might speak English mother tongue and needs his app/text/website translated to German. 
So I could do it for him and he for me. Without paying money, but with high quality, because both have a benefit. Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to find this guy, do you have an idea? Is there a platform on the internet which could help out?

My google research did not get a valuable result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to localize an iphone app for different languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118425/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-for-different-languages)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a professional service, speaking a language does not mean you can do a good translation.

There are a few recommended vendors from apple:
https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/#vendors

I work for [Supertext](http://www.supertext.ch/en) and we also do lots of [app translations](http://blog.supertext.ch/2012/09/ist-ihre-iphone-app-mehrsprachig/).

Comment: Thank you for this link, but unfortunately it seems to be too proffessional, the prices a far over my budget. :-(

Comment: If you need something cheaper, there is alway MyGengo. I'm pretty sure the offer iPhone localization too. But honestly, a bad translation is just not worth the money, you will just anger and confuse your customer.